# Queue in labview formula node

Tags: queue, dynamic-arrays, labview

Is there a way to get a queue of ints in the formula node of Labview?

I could use an array, initialize it outside with a max size and use that but is there another way? Maybe a sort of dynamic array?

Answer (score 1):

In LabVIEW you would basically do the same, however you wouldn't do it later since the parallel nature of LabVIEW
[image: Queue example]

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take here depends greatly on how the data is produced and consumed, but I'll outline a general use-case and hopefully it will apply.

You can fit this into a queued state machine architecture, where you wrap up your incoming integer value with any other metadata into a cluster (or just send it in bare), and put it in the stack to be processed with the Enqueue Element block. When the data is taken off the stack using the Dequeue Element block, you can process it using your formula node architecture and append it to a result array, or even put it in a different queue for processing.

I'd love to draw you a nice little snippet, but I haven't LV at this computer. See, however, slide 41 here for a great simple example: ftp://ftp.ni.com/pub/branches/uk/devdays_2011/Basic_Design_Patterns_in_LabVIEW.pdf

You'd put your formula node in the bottom of the two parallel loops. This separates the UI from the processing. It's a great design I use almost exclusively on UIs.

Comment: A queue of ints as in a fifo colection of integers. In c# you would write Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();, which would allow you to enqueue integers and later dequeue them starting from the first integer you enqueued.